# I want to `Add columns` to my database using `PDOquery`. But my query returns some error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to `Alter` my database table (Add Columns) using query.
I have done this :

**This is my first query (Run Successfully) :**

```
$database->pdoQuery("ALTER TABLE tbl_mytable ADD column1 varchar(100)");
```

**This is my second query (gives an error) :**

```
$database->pdoQuery("ALTER TABLE tbl_mytable ADD column2 text");
```

I have got this ***error message***:

```
Executed Query -> ALTER TABLE tbl_mytable ADD column2 text
ERROR:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 315"
```

Can any one solve my problem?
Any help would get appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$db->query("ALTER TABLE `tbl_mytable` ADD `column2` text NOT NULL AFTER `column1`");

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which versions you're using.

Your query is not wrong, but it could be your (older) MySQL version. Add backticks to your query:

```
$database->pdoQuery("ALTER TABLE `tbl_mytable` ADD `column2` text");
```

Comment: Tried but same result. :(